# Existence of ideal

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, ring-theory, ideals

Let $R$ be a ring, $I$ a finitely generated ideal of $R$ and $J$ an ideal of $R$ with $J \subset I$. Show that $R$ has an ideal $M$ so that $J \subset M \subset I$ and for every ideal $N$ with $M \subset N \subset I$ $\Rightarrow$ $N=M$ or $N=I$.

If I choose $M:=I+J=\{a+b,a \in I, b \in J\}$ then the first part should be proved?

For the second part I have to assume that if $N \neq M$ then it has to be equal to $I$ meaning there is at least one element in $N$ that is not in $I$?

Thanks for any help!

Comment: Maybe I'm mistaken, but I think it is a unique statement. Moreover note that since $J\subset I$, you have $I+J=I$. I don't know if you mean the inclusions $\subset$ as strict, in that case $M=I+J$  doesn't work

Comment: Your inclusions are probably meant to be strict, this is a proof of maximal proper sub-ideals of finitely generated ideals?

Comment: You may need the choice axiom

Comment: I think the question is asking you to come up with an $M$ that satisfies *both* conditions: i.e. $J\subset M \subset I$ AND if we come up with any other ideal $N$ then we cannot sandwich $N$ between $M$ and $I$. So your choice of $M$ won't work since $I + J = I$. Instead, think of the fact that $I$ is finitely generated (and hence so would $J$). That is, $\langle g_1,\ldots, g_n\rangle = J$ and $\langle g_1,\ldots, g_n, g_{n+1}, \ldots, g_{n+m}\rangle = I$ since the generating set of $J$ must be contained in $I$. Can you choose generators from these two sets which will satisfy your conditions?

Comment: @AliasK Thanks, but sorry, I don't come up with any generators that could fit? Would $⟨g_1,...,g_{n+1}⟩$ work (one more generator than $J$ but less than $I$?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a finite sequence $x_1,\cdots,x_n\in I$ such that
$$I=J+(x_1)+\cdots+(x_n).$$

So among all such sequences there is one of minimial length, and so we may assume $x_1,\cdots,x_n$ has a minimal length.Then
$$L=J+(x_2)+\cdots+(x_n)$$ is a proper ideal of $I$.

Let $\mathscr{F} $ be the set of  all  proper ideal of $I$ that contanin $L$. Clearly, $\mathscr{F} $ is a non-empty. Now an ideal $N$ that contains $L$ is in $\mathscr{F} $ if and only if $x_1\notin N$.

By zorn's lemma, $\mathscr{F} $ has a maximal element, say $M$. $M$ is the ideal satisfying the condition.